# Debugging Extjs 4 in Firebug

Tags: extjs, firebug, extjs4

I am having trouble debugging my Extjs 4 files in Firebug.
In the scripts tab of firebug I am only seeing app.js, ext-all-debug.js, and a bunch of files under /ext-4.0.7/ext-all-debug.js/eval/seq.
I am unable to see any of the javascript files for my custom extjs objects.

Comment: Open the NET tab and see if they're loaded or 404.

Comment: I've given up on debugging ExtJS with Firebug -- whenever it needs to refer to a line number within the big files like ext-all-debug.js, it's off by dozens if not hundreds of line numbers.  Don't know if anybody else has seen this, but I've switched to Chrome for this reason

Comment: Yea, Firebug tends to get buggier with every version.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty You're right Chrome works flawlessly.  It's a shame that Firebug doesn't work nearly as well.

Comment: Never use Firebug. It often generates weird error when I have the firebug panel turned on, and the bug will disappear when I off it. A lot of issue with it, so rather, better use g.chrome.

Comment: That's really too bad. I'd finally kicked the Chrome addiction and made it back over to support Mozilla. Arg!

Comment: Can't tell if [this answer from the Sencha support forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?162302-Firebug-does-not-show-all-js-files&p=712866&viewfull=1#post712866) is saying that, to debug in Firebug, you have to compile your app into a giant app.js.  I think the Firebug issue has to do with [lazy loading in ExtJS 4](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader): `Ext.Loader is the heart of the new dynamic dependency loading capability in Ext JS 4+.`  Chrome works great. Ditto @Jeb; I thought I'd gotten back to FF exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a problem debugging ExtJS in firebug at all. 
A super helpful addition to firebug  for ExtJS is Illuminations for Developers [plugin](http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/).  I highly highly recommend this tool, even if you just get the evaluation version. Paid version is even better and is worth every penny! I do not have any relationship with the creator other than I am a paying customer.

Having said that, Chrome stack traces generated by ExtJS are actually better. So I will switch to Chrome if I have a a consistent error that I want to trace.

Comment: Nice plugin for sure, but it doesn't help with the problem of debugging all the scripts.